# How to get asterisk* at the end of children to be red colored?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

When required prop is true, I want * at the end of children to be red colored. Current code below is printing out 'Label Component*'. Before the change, I had it {required ? `${children} * : children} and it worked except * was default black color. All I'm trying to do is turn it into red colored * and facing difficulties. What am I doing wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/label-component-ts-zw392?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1356

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface ILabelProps {
  weight?: "normal" | "bold";
  htmlFor?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  testId?: string;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const Label: React.FunctionComponent<ILabelProps> = ({
  htmlFor,
  weight = "normal",
  testId,
  required = false,
  children
}: ILabelProps) => {
  const dataRef = React.useRef(null);

  const createTestId = (
    ref: HTMLElement,
    testId: string | undefined,
    testIdName: string = "data-testid"
  ) => {
    if (ref && testId) {
      ref.setAttribute(testIdName, testId);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dataRef.current) {
      createTestId(dataRef.current, testId);
    }
  }, [dataRef, testId]);

  const requiredAsterisk = `<span color="red">*</span>`;

  return (
    <label ref={dataRef} htmlFor={htmlFor} style={{ fontWeight: weight }}>
      {required ? (
        <span>
          {children}
          {requiredAsterisk}
        </span>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </label>
  );
};

export const Content: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Label
      htmlFor="some-id"
      testId="testing-label"
      weight="normal"
      required={true}
    >
      Label Component
    </Label>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `<span style="color: red">*</span>`?

Comment: Inside <label>, put `{children}`  then `{required && <span style={{ color: "red" }}> *</span>}`

Comment: wrap only the asterisk inside the span :  `return (
    <label ref={dataRef} htmlFor={htmlFor} style={{ fontWeight: weight }}>      
      {children}
      {required ? (
        <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
          {requiredAsterisk}
        </span>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </label>
  );`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the color with a color prop. If you want to set it inline it needs to be inside a 'style' prop as mentioned above. So line 36 becomes

```
const requiredAsterisk = <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span>;
```